# How select data within brackets in pandas data frame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas data frame. The column of my data frame that I am interested contains strings.
Within the string there is a section that has brackets. It looks like so:

```
Some Data (More Info)
Some Data (More Info)
Some Data (More Info)
```

What I am trying to do is select the data that’s in between the brackets and stick it into a new column.
I was been playing around with split but I cant get it to work because I am left with an extra ‘)’ at the end of the string.
Is there away to select the data with out having the brackets without have this little bracket left over?
I don't think I can split by just spaces alone because my `some data` has spaces in it.

I am splitting the data by:

```
df_split = df_abc['title'].str.split('(', expand=True)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`str.extract`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html):

```
res = df_abc['title'].str.extract(r'\((.*?)\)')
print(res)
```

**Output**

```
           0
0  More Info
1  More Info
2  More Info
```

As an alternative use a [named capturing group](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax), to obtain a column name:

```
res = df_abc['title'].str.extract(r'\((?P<text>.*?)\)')
print(res)
```

**Output**

```
        text
0  More Info
1  More Info
2  More Info
```

It also may be worth to take a look [`str.extractall`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extractall.html) for multiple occurrences of the pattern.